# Does Hazelcast have a distributed priority queue implementation?

Tags: caching, distributed, priority-queue, hazelcast, in-memory

We need to implement a distributed priority queue within Hazelcast at the moment and the only documentation we can find on the matter is this: https://blog.hazelcast.com/priority-queueing-using-spi/, which is not a production ready implementation.

It references `MigrationAwareService` and `BackupAwareOperation` interfaces and provides a basic example for how to implement them, but after inspecting Hazelcast's own `QueueService` it doesn't look like these examples will suffice. Is it better to use `QueueService` as guidance instead?

On top of this, it looks as though there is no documentation or examples to make this custom distributed object adhere to Hazelcast's client-server protocol.

Does Hazelcast have any plans to implement this object in the near future? I've discovered `OperationQueue` - is this a distributed priority queue implementation we can use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The answer to "why doesn't X have Y" questions is usually "because the developers didn't add it." Questions about why it isn't there or whether there are plans to add it are better asked of the developers rather than on a public forum. If no plans have been announced, than it's likely that telling you about it would be a breech of somebody's confidentiality agreement.

Comment: This isn't "why doesn't Hazelcast" -  it is "does Hazelcast" -  and it should have the opportunity to be answered as it is relevant to a multitude of engineers and businesses in 2018.

Comment: Your question title is "Why doesn't  . . ." And, as I said, your question is better answered by the Hazelcast dev team. But that's just my opinion. Others might think differently.

Comment: If there are finite number of priorities you need, eg high/medium/low, you could have a queue for each and poll them in sequence.